# Save image as string with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, base64, sharedpreferences

I'm writing an app which in I have to save the state of the `Activity`. 
I have an `ImageView` and a `Button` on the screen. When I click on the `Button` the `ImageView` change the background image. My problem is when I stop the `Activity` and start it again the `ImageView` shows the first image. I converted my image into a `String` with **Base64**. Then I saved the string with `SharedPreferences`. After that i got it and decode again with **Base64**. I dont have any error message but it's not working. I copy my code and if anyone has an idea how to do it please response!

```
public static final String IMAGE = "Image";
public static final String DB_INIT = "DB_INIT";

Button button;
ImageView imageview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            DB_INIT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String backimage = sp.getString(IMAGE, "res/drawable/my_image.png");

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.szaz);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            DB_INIT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et = sp.edit();
    et.putString(IMAGE,"res/drawable/my_image.png");
    et.commit();
    super.onStop();
  }
}
```

Comment: My question is... **why**? you could simply store the **image path**.

Comment: I tried to save it and after it didn't work i tried another way. I didn't find how to store the image path. Can you tell me please?

Comment: It's way **easier** and **more efficient** than storing a whole image as an ASCII representation.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how can i do it? I was looking for how to do that but i didn't find it. Can you tell me how to store the image path?

Comment: How do you save a string in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Like i did in my code. I wirte to shared preferences file first,by calling edit(). Pass the keys and values i want to write with putString(). Then retrieve values from a sharedpreferences file call getString().

Comment: Exactly. Then, what is the problem in writing a file path?

Comment: So you are saying i should store the image path ( like:res/drawable/image) with shadredprefrences. I can save type int,long,float,boolean,string with sharedprefrences. How can i save the path of something? Sorry for my ignorance but i dont understand how to do that.

Comment: an **id** is an **int**, in case you want to save the id (`like:res/drawable/image`) a **path** is a **string**, i.e.: `"./files/my_image.png"`

Comment: I edited my code and it's still not working. Maybe should write the path another way?

Comment: `et.putString(IMAGE,res/drawable/my_image.png);` (same for `getString()`) - Come on, **seriously**. This isn't even a string! To be a string it should be enclosed in double quotes. But you are saving the id... which is an integer, doesn't require the extension and should be retrieved by using `getIdentifier()`. I think you have still a lot to study.

Comment: Sorry I spoiled the edit, but in my code i used doble quotes and its not working. thank you for your help. :)